# Console shows errors in System.Linq.Enumerable and Bee.TundraBackend when build an android app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build

I have this error when build my android app in Unity. I have remove the build cache folders and Bee folder but the error persists when build again. Can anyone help me? We don't find what we are doing wrong.

```
Internal build system error. BuildProgram exited with code 3.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator`1.Select[TResult](Func`2 selector)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Select[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 selector)
at Bee.TundraBackend.TundraBackend.AddDependency(NPath from, IEnumerable`1 to, DependencyKind kind)
at Bee.NativeProgramSupport.Lumping.SetupLumps(ArtifactLocationPolicy artifactLocationPolicy, List`1 inputInstructions, Int32 idealFilesPerLump)+MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
at System.Collections.Generic.SparseArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
at System.Collections.Generic.SparseArrayBuilder`1.ReserveOrAdd(IEnumerable`1 items)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Concat2Iterator`1.ToArray()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Bee.NativeProgramSupport.NativeProgram.ProduceObjectFileProductionInstructions(NativeProgramConfiguration config, ArtifactLocationPolicy artifactLocationPolicy, ObjectFileProducer[] objectFileProducers, NPath[]& additionalObjectFiles, NPath[]& foundHeaders)
at Bee.NativeProgramSupport.NativeProgram.SetupSpecificConfigurationImpl(NativeProgramConfiguration config, NativeProgramFormat format, ObjectFileProducer[] objectFileProducers)
at Bee.NativeProgramSupport.NativeProgram.SetupSpecificConfiguration(NativeProgramConfiguration config, NativeProgramFormat format, ObjectFileProducer[] objectFileProducers)
at Bee.NativeProgramSupport.NativeProgram.SetupLibraryDependencies(NativeProgramConfiguration config, ToolChain toolchain, ObjectFileProducer[] objectFileProducers)
at Bee.NativeProgramSupport.NativeProgram.SetupSpecificConfigurationImpl(NativeProgramConfiguration config, NativeProgramFormat format, ObjectFileProducer[] objectFileProducers)
at Bee.NativeProgramSupport.NativeProgram.SetupSpecificConfiguration(NativeProgramConfiguration config, NativeProgramFormat format, ObjectFileProducer[] objectFileProducers)
at PlayerBuildProgramLibrary.PlayerBuildProgramBase.SetupIl2CppBuild() in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/IncrementalBuildPipeline/PlayerBuildProgramLibrary/PlayerBuildProgramBase.cs:line 369
at PlayerBuildProgramLibrary.PlayerBuildProgramBase.SetupPlayerBuild() in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/IncrementalBuildPipeline/PlayerBuildProgramLibrary/PlayerBuildProgramBase.cs:line 171
at AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.SetupPlayerBuild()
at PlayerBuildProgramLibrary.PlayerBuildProgramBase.RunBuildProgram() in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/IncrementalBuildPipeline/PlayerBuildProgramLibrary/PlayerBuildProgramBase.cs:line 165
at PlayerBuildProgramTypeWrapper.Run(String[] args)
at Program.Main(String[] args)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)


BuildFailedException: Incremental Player build failed!
UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/Modules/BeeBuildPostprocessor.cs:604)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/Modules/DefaultBuildPostprocessor.cs:28)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <51e10b9352934e7f80981b508a072fc6>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:370)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy Thank you Roman, but how can we locate the object reference that not set to an instance of an object?

Comment: You 've attentively read the "Debugging" section of the answer, haven't you?

Comment: Have you tried a full build?

Comment: @shingo How can I do a full build?

Comment: [Creating non-incremental builds](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.2/Documentation/Manual/incremental-build-pipeline.html#creating-non-incremental-builds)

Comment: @shingo Yes, we have done cleaned builds but it appears same errors. Only when we restart the computer and open the unity project again the build is fine without errors. How can we solve it?

Comment: Has anybody a solution for this problem? Why do I have this error when I build the project just after other build without errors and I have to restart my computer and delete LIBRARY/BEE, LIBRARY/PLAYERDATACACHE and LIBRARY/BUILDPLAYERDATA?